# Chrome Extension interact with page (not in tab) in background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I make a extension that interact with a page in background (not in tab)? for example check www.google.com each 5 minutes while I have only www.yahoo.com open.

I have made the function of the extension but I need to know how to use it without having this page open.

Regards.

Comment: Will google be open in another tab? If so, look into: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query If it won't be, then I would recommend using an API to query the desired websites(google.com) and return data by communicating through that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying you want to interact with `https://www.google.com` without opening it, you could make an ajax call in background page. Steps would be like the following:

1. Add `https://www.google.com/*` in `permissions` field in `manifest.json`

   ```
   "permissions": ["https://www.google.com/*"]
   ```
2. Make an ajax call in background page.

   ```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onload = function() {
       var data = xhr.responseText;
       // Your logic to handle response data
   };
   xhr.open("GET", "https://www.google.com");
   xhr.send();
   ```